# While loop phone number

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get this while loop to run correctly, and i am struggling to figure out how to get multiple inputs of phone numbers from the user and then close out the loop

I have tried equating the ct to num and other variables

I want the code to:

1. Take a phone number
2. then ask if the user wants to enter more
3. if they don't

   - it should exit out the loop.
4. If they do

   - then it should continue until the number reaches 6

```py
ct=0

while ct<=6:
    phonenumbertype= input(' choose one of the following number types cell,work , other : ')
    areacode= int(input(' Please enter your areacode :'))
    phonenumberexchange= int(input(' Please enter first three numbers after area code :'))
    linenumber= int(input(' Please enter the last 4 digits / numbers: '))

Answer = input('Would you like to enter another number? you only have two slots left: Y or N')
```

Comment: Inside the `while loop` you need to increase `ct`.  Use `ct+=1`.  Currently, the loop while continue indefinitely because `ct` is always `<6`

Comment: The Code you selected as the answer doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `break` statement. You have also not incremented `ct`.

I'm starting with 6 here as you want number of slots to be printed

```
ct=6

while ct<0:
    phonenumbertype= input(' choose one of the following number types cell,work , other : ')
    areacode= int(input(' Please enter your areacode :'))
    phonenumberexchange= int(input(' Please enter first three numbers after area code :'))
    linenumber= int(input(' Please enter the last 4 digits / numbers: '))
    choice = input('Would you like to enter another number? you only have ' , ct,  ' slots left: Y or N')
     if choice.upper() == 'N':
       break
     ct -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

- Given the text of `Answer`, in your question, it seems the goal is to collect a number and offer the user the opportunity to enter two more numbers.

  - One number for each `cell`, `work`, and `other`, which means the `while loop` should continue for a maximum of 3 times, not 6
- The `while loop` should stop after all 3 numbers have been entered, or the person enters any upper or lowercase variation of `n` or `no`
- It's not stated, but assumed, the entries should be stored.

  - A `dict` will be used to store each entry
  - This is one of a number of forms the `dict` could take

```py
ct = 0

phone_numbers = {'type': [],
                 'area': [],
                 'exchange': [],
                 'line': []}

numbers_allowed = 3

while True:
    phone_numbers['type'].append(input('Choose one of the following number types cell, work , other: '))

    phone_numbers['area'].append(int(input('Please enter your area code: ')))

    phone_numbers['exchange'].append(int(input('Please enter first three numbers after area code: ')))

    phone_numbers['line'].append(int(input('Please enter the last 4 digits / numbers: ')))

    ct+=1
    if ct == numbers_allowed:
        print('You have entered all the available numbers.  Thanks')
        break

    Answer = input(f'You may enter {numbers_allowed - ct} more numbers.  Y, to enter another number, otherwise N: ')

    if Answer.lower() in ['n', 'no']:
        break

print(phone_numbers)
```

#### Output 1:

```py
Choose one of the following number types cell, work , other:  cell
Please enter your area code:  111
Please enter first three numbers after area code:  111
Please enter the last 4 digits / numbers:  1111
You may enter 2 more numbers.  Y, to enter another number, otherwise N: y
Choose one of the following number types cell, work , other:  work
Please enter your area code:  222
Please enter first three numbers after area code:  222
Please enter the last 4 digits / numbers:  2222
You may enter 1 more numbers.  Y, to enter another number, otherwise N: y
Choose one of the following number types cell, work , other:  other
Please enter your area code:  333
Please enter first three numbers after area code:  333
Please enter the last 4 digits / numbers:  3333
You have entered all the available numbers.  Thanks
{'area': [111, 222, 333],
 'exchange': [111, 222, 333],
 'line': [1111, 2222, 3333],
 'type': ['cell', 'work', 'other']}
```

#### Output 2:

```py
Choose one of the following number types cell, work , other:  cell
Please enter your area code:  111
Please enter first three numbers after area code:  111
Please enter the last 4 digits / numbers:  1111
You may enter 2 more numbers.  Y, to enter another number, otherwise N:  n
{'area': [111], 'exchange': [111], 'line': [1111], 'type': ['cell']}
```